# How to display the phone's gallery in MWPhotoBrowser swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mwphotobrowser

I need to create a multiple selection image picker for iOS and iPad app and I am looking into the MWPhotoBrowser but not able to find if this library can show the phone's gallery in its grid view for multiple selection. Is this possible in this library or is there any library which can be used in its place.

Comment: plz try BSImagePicker for multiple image selection, below is the BSImagePicker GitHub path. :   https://github.com/mikaoj/BSImagePicker

Answer (score 0):

[Please check Dkimage image picker controller it's best lib for multiple image selection](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController)